# Pass input textbox value in onClick function - php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a input text field. I need to pass the values entered inside the element through onClick of javascript.

```
<form>
<fieldset>     
  <label>Common Site ID: </label><span><?php echo $commonsiteid ?></span><br>
  <label>Acres: </label><input id="acre_value" name="acre_value" type="text" value="<?php echo $acre; ?>">
 </fieldset>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="saveValue('<?php echo $_REQUEST['acre_value'] ?>')">
```

I am passing the value through submit onClick, Which is going empty. How do i pass value in this onclick function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried writing something like following.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="saveValue(document.getElementById('acre_value').value)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="saveValue(document.getElementById('acre_value').value);">
```

Answer (score 1):

I try this, and worked:

```
<script>
    function saveValue(){
        alert(document.formName.hiddenField.value);
        /*do something*/
        return false;
    }
</script>
<form name="formName" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['acre_value'] ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="saveValue()">
</form>
```

As you can see, i pass the value by a hidden field, and on the Js function i get the value of this field.
If you need a php function instead off a js, it's the same logic.